# Is it possible to click and drag the title from one UIButton and drop it into the title of another UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two UIButton's and I want to be able to have the user click one of the UIButton's and drag it over to another UIButton and have the title of the UIButton moved from the first UIButton to the second one.  Is that possible?  Thanks.

Comment: yes this is possible, for this you have to use the touch detection methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title is an element of UIButton, so you can't use any predefined methods to do this. You'd have to create custom implementation where you added a draggable UILabel on touch, then set the button's title to match on release - or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created another answer that will at least get you on your way, it implements the press, the drag, and the up events for a button, where you are trying to recognize another button that you have dragged to!!!

[Xcode iOS push down button and drag then up on a second button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121827/xcode-ios-push-down-button-and-drag-then-up-on-a-second-button/11121956#comment14578641_11121956)

Look at the answer provided by me!