# Xcode iOS push down button and drag then up on a second button

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, touch, drag

Lets say I wan't to add 1 to an integer. This will only be done when I push down on a `UIButton` and then release my finger on another `UIButton`. **A drag combo.** Whats the easiest way I can make an `IBAction` occur out of a combo? This could be done with touch coordinates or maybe just `UIButtons` and `IBActions`.

### How do I create a 2-button combo with `IBActions`

Comment: I have updated my answer with completely tested code, IT DOES WORK!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try implementing the button you wish to touch down on as a "Touch Down", "Touch Up Inside", and "Touch Up Outside" button.

UIButtons can respond to many differing types of events
Touch Cancel
Touch Down
Touch Down Repeat
Touch Drag Enter
Touch Drag Exit
Touch Drag Inside
Touch Drag Outside
Touch Up Inside
Touch Up Outside

You can implement different action code for each of these for each button for best control of whatever you wish.  The simplistic case only uses the 2 I mentioned above.

THIS CODE HAS BEEN TESTED AND DOES WORK

In your ViewController header file (here was mine):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton * upButton;    // count up when finger released button
    IBOutlet UIButton * downButton;
    IBOutlet UILable * score;
    BOOL isButtonDown;
    unsigned int youCounter;
}

-(IBAction)downButtonDown:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)downButtonUpInside:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)downButtonDragOutside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event;
-(IBAction)downButtonUpOutside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

In your .xib, connect the down button (the one you wish to be your original finger pressed button) to the proper actions above.

In your ViewController.m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isButtonDown = NO;
    youCounter   = 0;
}

-(IBAction)downButtonDown:(id)sender{
    isButtonDown = YES;
}

-(IBAction)downButtonUpInside:(id)sender{
    isButtonDown = NO;
}

-(IBAction)downButtonDragOutside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSArray theTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];

    [downButton setHighlighted:YES];

    if(YES == [upButton pointInside:[[theTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:upButton] withEvent:event]){
        [upButton setHighlighted:YES];
    }else{
        [upButton setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}

-(IBAction)downButtonUpOutside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(YES == [upButton pointInside:[[theTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:upButton] withEvent:event]){
        youCounter++;
        score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score = %d", youCounter];
    }

    [downButton setHighlighted:NO];
    [upButton setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

Comment: `Touch Up Inside` only gets sent when the touch started inside of the button.  If you drag from outside of a button and then let up inside of the button it does not call `Touch Up Inside` on that control.

Comment: Yes Im trying to think through this one, as there has to be an easier way than the answer Jeremy provided, I began thinking that way, then tryed to think within the confines of the Apple Button APIs!!!  +1 to Jeremy

Comment: @comradsky - Should be coming on its way (or there :-)!!!  Look at the console output as well, to get a better picture into what is going on!!!

Comment: What do you mean the variable in the middle?

Comment: I have sent you another email with a new revision of code with all of what you've asked.

Answer (score 3):

```
 //Initalize a BOOL variable to know if you started the touch in the right place.
 BOOL correctStart = NO;

 //Get the location of the first touch, if its in the first button make correctStart = YES.
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
           for (UITouch *touch in allTouches) {
                if ([touch locationInView:button1.view]) {
                     correctStart = YES;
                }
           }
 }

 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
           for (UITouch *touch in allTouches) {
                if (([touch locationInView:button2.view]) && (correctStart == YES)) {
                     anInteger++;
                }
           }
      correctStart = NO;
 }
```

I did not try this code as I am not at my mac, so your results may vary, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @comradsky As I said, I am currently not at my Mac. When I get home after work if you are still having problems I will troubleshoot my code for you.

Comment: Thank you so much jeremey. To be clear its that i set up my buttons as ibactions in the .h and your code of course belongs in .m. So i will try but i will probably need your help. But i learned a lot. thanks again

Comment: This code doesnt work either, locationInView returns a CGPoint, not a boolean!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and track the location in your buttons. I found this to be more readable. (I actually ended up using UILabels because I didn't need any further `UIButton` behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

// Create a button, add targets

```
UIButton *cloudButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [cloudButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification_add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cloudButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [cloudButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent: )
           forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cloudButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent: )
           forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
        [cloudButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent: )
           forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside |
         UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

        [self.view addSubview:cloudButton];
```

//event methods

```
- (void) dragBegan: (UIControl *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragBegan......");
}

- (void) dragMoving: (UIControl *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragMoving..............");
}
- (void) dragEnded: (UIControl *) c withEvent:ev
{
    NSLog(@"dragEnded..............");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following for the first UIButton in the `ViewDidLoad` method

```
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];

    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside |
     UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

In the `dragMoving` method

```
- (void)dragMoving:(UIControl *)c withEvent:event{

    NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:[button2 superview]];


        if ( CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, currentPoint) ) {
            NSLog(@"over second button); 
        } 
    }
```

As for the `dragEnded` method:

```
- (void) dragEnded:(UIControl *)c withEvent:event{

    NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:[self.button1 superview]];
        if ( CGRectContainsPoint(button2.frame, currentPoint) ) {
            NSLog(@"ended on button 2");
            //add 1 to the integer


        }
    else {
        NSLog(@"not on button 2");
    }
}
```