# Click and drag to another button

Tags: iphone

There is an app call DurionLite (free on iPhone) which plays a word game where letters are clicked and dragged into word construction slots to create words.  As the dragged letter gets near the construction slots, the borders of the nearest construction slot is highlighted and if you then release the letter, it goes into the highlighted construction slot.  You can also then click and drag letters from the construction slots (although not back to their original locations).  I'm trying to do a similar thing but can't figure out how that can be done.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yes go to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121827/xcode-ios-push-down-button-and-drag-then-up-on-a-second-button
i hope i was helpful

Comment: I tried using TouchDown and TouchUp, but the TouchUp only registers as an event with the original UIButton, not the UIButton where the TouchUp occurred.  I also tried some Drag events but they didn't work either.

Comment: @comradsky your comment says that the solution offered didn't work.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one worked man. It seems more complicated but part of the code doesn't even need to be there.

Comment: It needed a few changes (in particular, the NSArray part didn't work as written), but it basically worked.